# favorite cardview with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-cardview

I am working in some project and I want to set favorite icon to card view and I want to show cardview detail to another activity. I use firebase for set cardview with recyclerview .

I am beginner in android. So I want some help to fix this part.

How can I get detail of cardview when I click on favorite icon and set the cardview detail to another recycler view?!?!?!?!

```
viewHolder.mStarBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
        mProccessStar = true;
        mDatabaseStar.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (mProccessStar) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(post_key1).hasChild(mAuth1.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
                        mDatabaseStar.child(post_key1).child(mAuth1.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
                        mProccessStar = false;
                    } else {
                        mDatabaseStar.child(post_key1).child(mAuth1.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(post_key1);
                        mProccessStar = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
});
```

I want to copy all this string and show it to another recyclerview , right now i set this string to an recyclerview with cardview.
I dont want to get key or get id.i want to get string of title and atring of desc and string of image

```
KPhBVHz4cmukSY...
```

desc: 
"کیف دست دوز"

image: 
"https://firebasestorage.google...

title: "کیف دست دوز"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabaseStar.push();
                                newPost.child("title").setValue(model.getTitle());
                                newPost.child("desc").setValue(model.getDesc());
```

mDatabaseStar.child(post_key1).child(mAuth1.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(newPost);

Answer (score 0):

You can do things with each CardView in the populateViewHolder. In this example:

1) The text is set (setText) for vName and vMessage

2) With getRef(i).getKey() you can get the parent key for the data displayed in the card.

3) An OnClickListener can also be set here on in thing in the CardView or in this case even the CardView itself.

```
mRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataModel, ViewHolder>(
                    DataModel.class,
                    R.layout.item_list,
                    ViewHolder.class,
                    mDatabaseRef
            ) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final DataModel student, int i) {
                    viewHolder.vName.setText(student.getName());
                    viewHolder.vMessage.setText(student.getMessage());

                    String itemId = getRef(i).getKey();


                    viewHolder.vCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(final View v) {
                            aMethodThatDoesSomething();

                        }
                    });
                    DatabaseReference mFavourite= mRef.child("shortlisted_tutors").child(currentUID1).child(otherUserUID);
                        mFavourite.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
                                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                    viewHolder.favoriteImageButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_bookmarkchecked);

                                }
                                else {
              viewHolder.favoriteImageButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_shortlistbookmark);

                                }
                            }

                    }
                };

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

Three things to note:
1) You will have to define each view (TextView, ImageView and etc) in the ViewHolder Class.
2) To be able to change the favourite ImageView/ImageButton from within **addValueEventListener** you will have to declare the ViewHolder as final in **populateViewHolder**
3) Here I just use if **dataSnapshot.exists()** but you could also request a value and change it based on it. However, **dataSnapshot.exists()** is quicker and more efficient in most cases.

Comment: Yes.i use populateViewholder but i what to set data of each cardview his favorite buttom clicked to another activity.


mDatabaseStar.addValueEventListener (new ValueEventListener (){
@Override
public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){




if (mProccessStar) {
if (dataSnapshot.child (post_key1).hashChild (mAuth1.getCurrentUser ().GetUid ())){
mDatabaseStar.Child (post_key1).Child (mAuth1.getCurrentUser ().getUid ()).removeValue ();
mProccessStar = false;

}else {

mDatabaseStar.child (post_key1).child (mAuth1.getCurrentUser().getUid ()).setValue ();
...

Comment: I've edited my answer let me know if you still have any questions

Comment: I have this part in my code.

This not my problem
If i click on favorite btn i want to get src of title and desc and image of cardview and put it in new string in my web database and call them in another activity.
Is it this question clear!?!?

Comment: So basically you want to copy the information in the card to another DatabaseReference that is then used to populate another recyclerview?

Comment: This answer do not copy card detail.just for get id . I find out the answer but is it not this.
Your answer just for click the button and not pass the data.but tnx for helping

Answer (score 0):

To copy a node do this:

```
    mRefToCopy = mRef.child("original_data");
    HashMap<String, Object> hashMapContainingCopy = new HashMaTp<>();
    mSubmittedTutorFeedback.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            hashMapContainingCopy = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Then copy it to the new location:

```
 mNewLocation.setValue(hashMapContainingCopy, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference reference) {
                            if (databaseError != null) {
                                Log.e("tutor feedback write", "Failed to write message", databaseError.toException());
                            }
                            else {
                                mRefToCopy.removeValue(new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                                    }
```

The last part is if you want to remove the original if the copy happened successfully. Please mark this answer as correct if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Perhaps make the  HashMap<String, Object> hashMapContainingCopy  a private variable